# Paralel for loop, map() works, pool.map() gives TypeError

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am making a condensed (only upper right) distance matrix. The calculation of the distance takes some time, so I want to paralelise the for loop. The unparelalised loop looks like

```
spectra_names, condensed_distance_matrix, index_0 = [], [], 0 
for index_1, index_2 in itertools.combinations(range(len(clusters)), 2):
    if index_0 == index_1:
        index_0 += 1
        spectra_names.append(clusters[index_1].get_names()[0])
    try:
        distance = 1/float(compare_clusters(clusters[index_1], clusters[index_2],maxiter=50))
    except:
        distance = 10
    condensed_distance_matrix.append(distance)
```

where clusters is a list of objects to compare, `compare_clusters()` is a likelihood function and `1/compare_clusters()` is the distance between two objects.

I tried to paralelise it by moving the distance function out of the loop like so

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
condensed_distance_matrix = []
spectra_names = []
index_0 = 0
clusters_1 = []
clusters_2 = []
for index_1, index_2 in itertools.combinations(range(len(clusters)), 2):
    if index_0 == index_1:
        index_0 += 1
        spectra_names.append(clusters[index_1].get_names()[0])
    clusters_1.append(clusters[index_1])
    clusters_2.append(clusters[index_2])
pool = Pool()
condensed_distance_matrix_values = pool.map(compare_clusters, clusters_1, clusters_2)

for value in condensed_distance_matrix_values :
    try:
        distance = 1/float(value)
    except:
        distance = 10
    condensed_distance_matrix.append(distance)
```

Before paralelising I tried the same code, but with `map()` instead of `pool.map()`. This worked as I wanted. However, when using `pool.map()` I get the error

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 225, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 288, in map_async
    result = MapResult(self._cache, chunksize, len(iterable), callback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 551, in __init__
    self._number_left = length//chunksize + bool(length % chunksize)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'list'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`Pool.map`'s documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map):

> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (**it supports only one iterable argument though**). It blocks until the result is ready.

For ordinary `map`, you can supply multiple iterables. For example,

```
>>> map(lambda x,y: x+y, "ABC", "DEF")
['AD', 'BE', 'CF']
```

But you can't do this with `Pool.map`. The third argument is interpreted as `chunksize`. You are giving it a list when it expects an int.

Perhaps you could pass in only a single iterable, by combining your lists:

```
pool.map(lambda (a,b): compare_clusters(a,b), zip(clusters_1, clusters_2))
```

I haven't tested it with `pool.map`, but this strategy works for ordinary `map`.

```
>>> map(lambda (a,b): a+b, zip("ABC", "DEF"))
['AD', 'BE', 'CF']
```

Comment: Ah I missed that. Any idea how this can be paralelised?

Comment: I've got an idea, although I haven't tested it. Edited.

Comment: The edit does not work: PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed. But I think I will ask a new question about this, since this question is answered.