# How to parallelize two iterators?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

This is a follow up from my question [Paralel for loop, map() works, pool.map() gives TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541523/paralel-for-loop-map-works-pool-map-gives-typeerror/). I want to do `multiprocessing.Pool.map(compare_clusters, clusters_1, clusters_2)`, where compare_clusters is a function, clusters_1 is a list of objects and clusters_2 is also a list of objects. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19541658/651779) to that question made it clear that unlike `map`, `multiprocessing.Pool.map`  can only take one iterator, and in this case `clusters_2` would have to be chunk size.

So my question is, how can I parallelize a loop with two iterators?

The code

```
spectra_names, condensed_distance_matrix, index_0 = [], [], 0 
for index_1, index_2 in itertools.combinations(range(len(clusters)), 2):
    if index_0 == index_1:
        index_0 += 1
        spectra_names.append(clusters[index_1].get_names()[0])
    try:
        distance = 1/float(compare_clusters(clusters[index_1], clusters[index_2],maxiter=50))
    except:
        distance = 10
    condensed_distance_matrix.append(distance)
```

How I tried to parallelize it

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
condensed_distance_matrix, spectra_names, index_0, clusters_1, clusters_2 = [], [], 0, [], []
for index_1, index_2 in itertools.combinations(range(len(clusters)), 2):
    if index_0 == index_1:
        index_0 += 1
        spectra_names.append(clusters[index_1].get_names()[0])
    clusters_1.append(clusters[index_1])
    clusters_2.append(clusters[index_2])
pool = Pool()
condensed_distance_matrix_values = pool.map(compare_clusters, clusters_1, clusters_2)

for value in condensed_distance_matrix_values :
    try:
        distance = 1/float(value)
    except:
        distance = 10
    condensed_distance_matrix.append(distance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.3 and later, you can use `pool.starmap`. In earlier versions you need to write a helper function:

```
def do_comparison(tupl):
    x, y = tupl # unpack arguments
    return compare_clusters(x, y)

pool = Pool()
values = pool.map(do_comparison, itertools.combinations(clusters, 2))
condensed_distance_matrix = [1 / float(v) if v != 0 else 10 for v in values]
```

I've simplified things a bunch by avoiding indexes completely, and instead directly generating 2-tuples of cluster values. You don't need your top `for` loop at all. I've also simplified the inverting code into a list comprehension, rather than a loop with `append` called once per item.

Of course, the other thing you were doing in your loop was extracting values for `spectra_names`. Instead of doing that one index at a time, I suggest using a list comprehension to build it all at once (it can be separate from the pool stuff above):

```
spectra_names = [c.get_names()[0] for c in clusters]
```

Comment: Thanks. In my actual code I have `spectra_names.append(clusters[-1].get_names())` after the loop to get the last value, but missed that when copying

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: Ah, that does make more sense. I'll edit to get rid of the last paragraph (and the slice it was talking about).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your code correctly then the following should work

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
condensed_distance_matrix = []
spectra_names = []
index_0 = 0
cluster_pairs = []
for index_1, index_2 in itertools.combinations(range(len(clusters)), 2):
    if index_0 == index_1:
        index_0 += 1
        spectra_names.append(clusters[index_1].get_names()[0])
    cluster_pairs.append((clusters[index_1], clusters[index_2]))
pool = Pool()
condensed_distance_matrix_values = pool.map(compare_clusters, cluster_pairs)

for value in condensed_distance_matrix_values :
    try:
        distance = 1/float(value)
    except:
        distance = 10
    condensed_distance_matrix.append(distance)
```

So, instead of creating two lists with single clusters in them, create one with tuples of cluster pairs. Each pair in the new list, is a cluster pair you want to compare. You'll probably need to adjust the `compare_clusters` function accordingly.

Taking into account `Blckknght`'s answer, you don't need to iterate over the indices to create a list of pairs that's what `itertools.combinations` is for. So you can just do `pool.map(compare_clusters, itertools.combinations(clusters, 2))` since combinations already returns a list of tuples.